# How to make convince compiler object will be an of a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm having a problem with inheritance and I don't know if it's a design flaw or not, and how to approach it if it is. I have a case with four classes: two bases and two derived. I'll use an alternative example:

```
class Player {  // base class for a player in general
    ...
}

class Game {    // base class for a game in general
    ...
    Player * players;    // dynamically allocated at run-time
    ...
}

class BaseballPlayer : public Player {
    ...
    void hitHomeRun();
    ...
}

class BaseballGame : public Game {
    ...
        ...
           players[i].hitHomeRun(); // this causes compiler error
}
```

The error I get is because the method isn't defined in the base class, but the array is of the type base class. In the `BaseballGame` class, only `BaseballPlayers` are loaded into the array, but I can't convince the compiler of that. Is this a matter of casting? How do I guarantee the compiler that `players` will be full of the correct objects? Can I override the `Player * players` member itself with a `BaseballPlayer * team` in the derived class?

Comment: Search for and read about *downcasting*.

Comment: I did this thing where i wrote a constructor BaseBallPlayer(Player&) and then just casted it. It compiles, but I'm worried it won't perform mutations on the original object...

Comment: Use C++ containers like  `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: @MichaelLongauer, that constructor creates a new object, you don't want that, you just want to cast the existing one to tell the compiler its type (using either `dynamic_cast` as suggested above, or if you're sure all the players in a `BaseballGame` are `BaseballPlayers` then you can just use `static_cast`). However, n.m.'s answer below is a cleaner option that requires no casting.

Comment: Yes, you have a huge design flaw. Your design is not object-oriented because `Player` does not seem to be designed as an object-oriented base class. It has no virtual functions; clients of `Player` must manually query the subtype to do something useful. You could probably eliminate all base classes in your design with little extra work.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much standard.

```
template <typename P>
class Game {
   std::vector<P> players;
...

class Player ...
class BaseballPlayer : public Player ...

class BaseballGame : public Game<BaseballPlayer> ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes this seems to be a design flaw. Your players are only going to be only `BaseBallPlayers` or `CricketPlayers`. While Player will be only contain the common info about player, ie. age, name, DOB etc. while  its specialization will contains its info about his records.

Two suggestions.
1> `class Game`: Every game has players. change `Player * players;`  to `Player * **players;` . So Game will contain dynamically allocated array of pointer to players.

2> `class BaseBallPlayer` and `class player`. Override the `BaseBallPlayer::hitHomeRun` and declare same as `virtual void Player::hitHomeRun`.

and change call to  `players[i].hitHomeRun()`; as  `dynamic_cast<BaballPlayer*>(players[i])->hitHomeRun();`. `virtual` override will call the `BaseBallPlayer::hitHomeRun`. `dynamic_cast` is only applicable for virtual inheritance or base class should contain at least one virtual method.

Comment: Neither suggestion makes sense to me. `Game` already contains a dynamically-allocated array of players, how does your suggestion help? And how does using a virtual base class help?

Comment: @jonathan: Well if you see I have created dynamic array of "pointer to players" and not to players. Well it could be vector of "pointer to players" as well. if you call any function of player, it will actually call the derived class method for a virtual function.

Comment: Yes, I know how virtual functions work. Changing to an array of pointers is not necessary for that to work. `Player* players = new BaseballPlayer[2]; static_cast<BaseballPlayer*>(players)[1].hitHomeRun();` works fine even  without a virtual function. If you are going to use a cast to the derived type then there's no point adding a virtual to the base class. (I see you've already fixed the suggestion to use a virtual base class, which doesn't help at all).